# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in .... on line 192

Tags: php, string, syntax-error, goto

I have this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/u1/public_html/scripts/easypanel.php on line 192

When i run that on the local it's work, but on the real server it's not:

**line 192 is**:

```
if(isset($_POST['send_pass']))
{
    if($_POST['post_password'] == $password)
    {
        goto content;# = line 192   
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<div class="box error">password incorrect</div><br>';
    }
}

...

content: 
    echo $content;
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Are you running PHP 5.3.0 or greater?  `<?php phpinfo() ?>`

Comment: Odd that it is complaining of `T_STRING` when there is no string on that line or the previous (except the array key, which is valid). You're sure that is 192?

Comment: do u mean the syntax (goto) not work on the v5 or higher ?

Comment: hope this script is not part of an `include`? the line number may not be correct. Remove that line from your code and see if it still complains

Comment: no it's not, i check it(how i can use goto) by the a sample in php.net, but for test can u send me the correct one ?

Comment: as recommened by @drew010  can you paste your server's php version here please.

Comment: and just for safety , please double check that there is no method called "goto" in your scripts as well.

Comment: @UmairKhan A method named `goto` can't be called as if it were a language construct.

Comment: @arxanas yes i am aware of that. I just asked him to ensure we werent looking at anything else than his problem.

Comment: @UmairKhan i check what u said in my phpinfo on the server, and i can't find goto. there is problem with my server!? i mean i should be update that? and tnx u for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your server version is 5.2. Thats what creating the problem. "goto" was introduced in 5.3. So you can either ask for an upgrade of the server version or stop using goto altogether because 5.2 does not support it.  It works fine on local because on local you are using PHP version 5.3

Comment: Great It was my pleasure. Please mark one of the answers as the chosen one now.

Answer (score 2):

The goto operator is available as of PHP 5.3.

Please check the version of your php on the local.

you can type `php -v` in the terminal to see the version.

Comment: What sort of twisted language *adds* a goto statement as it matures?

Comment: Hi, guys .. my php v on the local is 5.3.0 & php v on the server is 5.2.17 .

Comment: so, there is another syntax for use goto on this version? or other question: can i update my php version in the server ? thank u